# Pasar variable dentro de un ciclo, a otra funcion

Tags: typescript

Estoy seteando una variable dentro de un ciclo, pero necesito recuperarla en otra funcion para asi pushearla en un array.

PD: No puedo hacer el push dentro del if, debo hacerlo afuera.

Necesito utilizar la variable itemHistoria de este metodo...

```
public buscarOficiosTramite(tramite: Tramite) {

  var itemHistoria;

  this.respuestaGestionOficioService.existeOficios(tramite.id).subscribe(l => {

    if(l.existeOficio == true ){
    
      this.flagOficioResultado = true;

      itemHistoria = this.setearItemHistoriaConTramite(tramite);

    }else{

      this.flagOficioResultado = false;


      itemHistoria = this.setearItemHistoriaConTramite(tramite);

    }

    return itemHistoria;

      });


}
```

En el siguiente metodo dentro del forEach siendo pusheado en un array itemHistoria e itemsHistoriaFiltrados.

```
  private recorrerListaDeTramites(): void {

this.itemsHistoria = new Array<ItemHistoria>();
this.itemsHistoriaFiltrados = new Array<ItemHistoria>();

let documentoTramite: Documento;
this.listaDeTramites.forEach(item => {

  this.buscarOficiosTramite(item);

  this.itemsHistoria.push(this.itemHistoria);
  this.itemsHistoriaFiltrados.push(this.itemHistoria);
  
});
```

El problema que veo es que como la llamada al metodo que retornaria eventualmente el itemHistoria y el seteo estan dentro de un forEach, no encuentro la forma de obtener el valor y que no quede indefinido.

Como podria arreglar eso?

PD: Frente a la duda, esto es TS por que es un componente de Angular.

Comment: Eso es javascript puro?

Comment: eso es java, no JS

Comment: Pues que ponga bien las etiquetas, que ha puesto javascript y me estaba dando un sincope pues no pillaba nada :-) ... aunque me parece que eso es Angular y/o TypeScript

Comment: Disculpen, esto es parte de un componente en Angular, por tanto seria TypeScript

Comment: `this.buscarOficiosTramite(item);` si lo asignas a una variable ' let itemDe=this.buscarOficiosTramite(item)` luego `this.itemsHistoria.push(itemDe);` porque al declarar con var dentro del metodo a itemHistoria no lo veo nada bien